# Editing Image using Image Uri

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a image uri and I want to edit that image and obtain the new Image uri. After some searching I found this piece of code and tries to apply.

```
Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        editIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        editIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(editIntent, null), 222);
```

When I try to receive in callbacks I get `null` in data.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        System.out.println("REQUEST_CODE: " + requestCode + " " + resultCode + " " + data.getData());
    }
```

So how to get the new image uri or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ACTION_EDIT` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, as there is no result. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent?hl=en#ACTION_EDIT), particularly the "Output: nothing" portion.

What the other app does with the `Uri` is up to the other app. It might save changes to the original content identified by the `Uri` that you gave it, or it might not. If it elects to save changes to some new content, there is no means for you to find out where those changes were saved.

Comment: So how can I achieve editing the image? I mean how can I show all those editing options for the image

Comment: @Thullo: "So how can I achieve editing the image?" -- you are certainly welcome to use `ACTION_EDIT`, so long as you do not care about the results. "how can I show all those editing options for the image" -- I do not know what "all those editing options" are. You are certainly welcome to look into various image editing libraries, such as [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/6736), [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/2/5858), or [this one](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5876).

Comment: I got the result. I just noticed it is not changing the uri of the edited image. So it is working the way I want.